# Facebook Graph Api me/home Seems To Return Same as me/feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know there have already been a lot of questions asked about replicating the users home feed and using me/home, but my question is slightly different.

A few months ago I wrote code to authenticate with Facebook (get user access token) and then retrieve their home feed with me/home. This worked fine at the time as far as I can recall. I've just gone back to the code today, and it doesn't appear to work. The result I get back looks almost the same as me/feed, which is to say it is almost entirely posts from the same account and not posts from 'friends'. Just one post from someone else, a change to their profile pic, shows up but the rest are all 'self posts'.

This only happens with tokens for my own app. If I use graph explorer using the same token, I get the same result. If I use graph explorer with it's own token then it shows me something much more like the actual home feed on the Facebook site. Generating new tokens doesn't help. I have checked the permissions on the tokens used are the same, in fact I even copied the permission list from the generated graph token into my app and re-authenticated, but it didn't help. If my app does the request, then I get almost nothing from other people from me/home. This is the same if I use *myuserid*/home. Makes no difference.

So my question is, why? Have Facebook changed something and is there a way to change my app so it gets a better version of the home feed?

Secondly, while researching this I've discovered posts saying read_stream won't be granted by Facebook to any app on any platform that has an 'official facebook app'. Does this mean I'm out of luck anyway, even if I get this working for testing purposes using the account that owns the app, I won't actually be able to publish it so others can use it?

Thanks.

Comment: exactly, you will not get read_stream approved: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream

Comment: Thanks.So there is absolutely no (non-deprecated) way to retrieve the users home feed?

Comment: not if you want to go public with your app. you can only get the posts of the user with /me/posts, for example, but not the posts of his friends for privacy reasons.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I feared. Ruins my app idea, and shame it worked a few months ago when I first started (I wouldn't have spent so much time on it). Oh well.

Comment: @Yort have you looked at the permission "user_posts"? It provides access to the posts on a person's timeline and includes their own posts, posts they are tagged in, and posts other people make on their timeline.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_posts

Comment: Thanks Neil, that sounds useful but still not quite what I was looking for. It sounds like it still doesn't show posts made by people the user 'follows' but weren't made explicitly to that users timeline. What I really want to do, like most devs, is receive all the content the user sees on their news feed in the FB website. I will check it out anyway, it might be better than nothing. Thanks again.